# gomod, Which folders/files will be excluded?

Tags: go, go-modules

Golang use gomod, Some floder/files will be excluded. Such as example/include floder and *_test.go type file.

So, What are all the rules?

Comment: `*_test.go` are _not_ ignored/excluded.

Comment: no, if you use such `github.com/boltdb/bolt` project, you will can't found *_test.go file in vendor/github.com/boltdb/bolt path.

Comment: Yes, tests are not vendored but that doesn't mean test files are ignored. Please stop moving goalposts.

Answer (score 0):

The [Go tool documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns) says:

> Files in package documentation are ignored by the go command.

and

> Directory and file names that begin with "." or "_" are ignored by the go tool, as are directories named "testdata".

Additionally, the documentation for the [build command](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) says:

> When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'.

[Build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) can also be used to ignore files.